# How to put controller in another file in Angular 1.2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to separate the controller file from the module file (in app.js). But executing this in browser gives me an error. It works only if I put controller and module code in one file. But doesn't work if I put contoller in another file.

Here's my code for module (app.js):

```
 var CoursePlannerApp = angular.module("CoursePlannerApp", []);
```

And for the controller (CoursePlannerAppCtrl.js file):

```
CoursePlannerApp.controller("coursePlannerCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
```

Can anybody explain me please, why it doesn`t work? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the newly created js files script tag after the main modules js file tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app file

```
angular.module('app',[]); // initialise application
```

In your controller file

```
angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl', [function(){}]); //create controller
```

And make sure you loaded both files into the browser - app and than controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working with some kind of bundler (like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), you put all of your files on the global scope, therefore, you should manage the order of loading the files.

At your case, you should put `app.js` to load before `CoursePlannerAppCtrl.js`. In that way, `app.js` will put `CoursePlannerApp` on the window, and you will have an access to it from `CoursePlannerAppCtrl.js`.

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="CoursePlannerAppCtrl.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script tags in correct order. Just like below

```
<script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="CoursePlannerApp.js"></script>
<script src="coursePlannerCtrl.js"></script>
```